# ViewController segue to Nav Controller Immediately Pops off Nav Controller and returns to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a View Controller embedded in a Nav Controller for use with AWS Cognito.

I then have a separate stack that's segued to from the initial VC.

I have the 2nd stack embedded in its own Nav Controller, and I've tried push, show, and present modally. Each time I attempt to segue to the new Nav Controller, the segue is performed, then the new stack pops off, and I'm presented with the initial VC. Here's how my storyboard is set up:

[image]

Here's my prepare for segue:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FindTruth" {
      if let findTruthVC = segue.destination as? FindTruth {
        if let user = sender as? User {
        if let userDetails = self.userDetails {
          user.userDetails = userDetails
          print("User Details: \(userDetails) passed")
        }
          findTruthVC.user = user
          print("User: \(user.userId) passed")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Calling the segue:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FindTruth", sender: self.user)
```

There's no code nor storyboard reference from the 2nd stack to the initial stack/VC

Edit - When I set my storyboard as follows (with the segue from VC to VC) the view transitions, then the VC just goes blank, it doesn't transition back to the login View, but the app is unusable

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: [ios - Navigation between multiple NavigationControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558664/ios-navigation-between-multiple-navigationcontrollers)

Comment: Nevermind, I read the link after you edited. I tried doing it this way initially, but my nav bar button doesn't show up. I assumed because it was bypassing the Nav Controller

Comment: Yes. You can deal with Thread programmatically: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/understanding-threads-in-ios-5b8d7ab16f09

Comment: Yes from LoginVC to FindTruth - but now the entire screen is going blank, not just the nav bar items

Comment: The NavigationController should be as initial. Put the arrow on it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I just changed it, but its still the same - after segue the view loads then goes back to login VC

Comment: Ok, one step closer. I changed the segue from modal to push - the app is working again, and I have a nav bar on Find Truth, but the nav bar button isn't showing

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

well, Navigation controllers are an entirely different entity.
you cant push onto them.
You should use `self.present(UINavigationController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`